# Index as a NumericFields using Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, lucene

I needed to search a price field using lucene range query. However the results it gives are not accurate or consistent since I am using a TermRangeQuery in Lucene.Net API. I believe that using NumericRangeQuery I could get accurate results. To use NumericRangeQuery the field needs to be indexed using NumericField. Is there a way I can do this with Advanced Database Crawler.
I tried to do this by altering the Advanced Database Crawler source code but it is not working for me.

These are the changes I have done in Advanced Database Crawler. In scSearchContrib.Crawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler class in the CreateField method I have added the following code.

```
if (name.EndsWith("numeric"))
{
    field = new NumericField(name, storageType, true);
}
```

in the index configuration I  have given the field name name and appended the text "numeric" to it. However I am correctly passing the fieldname by removing the "numeric" part.

when building the index I get a error like this.

```
Job started: RebuildSearchIndex|System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Lucene.Net.Store.IndexOutput.WriteString(String s)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.FieldsWriter.WriteField(FieldInfo fi, Fieldable field)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.StoredFieldsWriterPerThread.AddField(Fieldable field, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocFieldProcessorPerThread.ProcessDocument()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.UpdateDocument(Document doc, Analyzer analyzer, Term delTerm)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.AddDocument(Document doc, Analyzer analyzer)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.AddDocument(Document doc, Analyzer analyzer)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.AddDocument(Document doc)
   at Sitecore.Search.IndexUpdateContext.AddDocument(Document document)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddItem(Item item, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.AddTree(Item root, IndexUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.Search.Index.Rebuild()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Search.RebuildSearchIndex.RebuildSearchIndexForm.Builder.Build()|Job ended: RebuildSearchIndex (units processed: 1)
```

Can someone tell me a way to do this using Advanced Database Crawler?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please include the modifications you tried to the Advanced Database Crawler, and details on what happened (exception thrown, no change in results, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I couldn't index as a numeric field found a work around for the problem. It is to index with padded zeros so the lucene TermRangeQuery give correct seach results. Every price is indexed with padded zeros so each value would contain 10 digits. That way the results I get are accurate.